# NDK debugging: ndk-gdb fails to pull app_process. Who and when creates the app_process binary?

Tags: android, windows, debugging, android-ndk, eclipse-adt

While investigating a problem with hitting breakpoints in native code, I decided to check if ndk-gdb works OK. I've deleted app_process, started Java debugging and ran `ndk-gdb --force`. Guess what, app_process is not created. `ndk-gdb --verbose` output has this line :

```
## COMMAND: adb_cmd pull /system/bin/app_process obj/local/armeabi-v7a/app_process
remote object '/system/bin/app_process' not a file or directory
Pulled app_process from device/emulator.
```

I've uninstalled the app from the target device, rebooted the device and repeated. Still no app_process. So, I wonder what's the problem here, and I also wonder when is this file created, and by what process / script.

Comment: app_process is a device binary created by the full device build.  It's the unspecialized "zygote" application process.  It's not part of the NDK.

Comment: @fadden: so I have no app_process binary. How could it happen and what do I do? Everything works fine, btw, except for debugging.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned before, Android 5.0 has `/system/bin/app_process` as a symlink to `/system/bin/app_process32`. Since a symlink cannot be pulled with `adb pull`, the `ndk-gdb` script will not be able to work as-is.

Change `ndk-gdb` as follows to support api21 changes as well as backwards compatibility for < api21:

```
# Get the app_server binary from the device
APP_PROCESS=$APP_OUT/app_process
if [ "$API_LEVEL" -lt "21" ] ; then
    run adb_cmd pull /system/bin/app_process `native_path $APP_PROCESS`
    log "Pulled app_process from device/emulator to $APP_PROCESS"
else
    run adb_cmd pull /system/bin/app_process32 `native_path $APP_PROCESS`
    log "Pulled app_process32 from device/emulator to $APP_PROCESS"
fi
```

EDIT: or:

```
# Get the app_server binary from the device
APP_PROCESS=$APP_OUT/app_process
APP_PROCESS_DEVICE=app_process32
if [ "$API_LEVEL" -lt "21" ] ; then
    APP_PROCESS_DEVICE=app_process
fi
run adb_cmd pull /system/bin/$APP_PROCESS_DEVICE `native_path $APP_PROCESS`
log "Pulled $APP_PROCESS_DEVICE from device/emulator to $APP_PROCESS"
```

Original Change is also here: http://pastebin.com/YfxNs06U. Note that this change renames `app_process32` to `app_process` when it is pulled to your development machine to support having a single debugging config in Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem. My device is running Android 5.0 preview, and app_process there is a symlink to a file called app_process32. So pulling app_process32 works fine.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer of Violet Giraffe, exchange in the script ndk-gdb the line

```
run adb_cmd pull /system/bin/app_process `native_path $APP_PROCESS`
```

with

```
run adb_cmd pull /system/bin/app_process32 `native_path $APP_PROCESS`
```

This solved the problem for me for this Android 5.0 issue and I was able to build and debug as before.

Comment: Yep. What I couldn't try a way to do is to automate the selection between app_process and app_process32 in ndk-gdb.