# Packaging error: Command "adb.exe -s emulator-5554 pull /system/bin/app_process" failed.Exit code: 1

Tags: android, c++, qt, qt-creator, build-error

I'm trying to build an empty new project project for Android target from Qt Creator, but I'm getting this error:

```
12:51:05: Packaging error: Command "C:/adt/sdk/platform-tools/adb.exe -s emulator-5554 pull /system/bin/app_process C:/Workspace/NewProjects/build-untitled18-Android_for_x86_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_4_2-Debug/app_process" failed.Exit code: 1
```

Screenshot:

[image]

And [the full log](http://pastebin.com/KqXRhAAY), in case needed.

How do I fix that error?

Answer (score 0):

After reading [the answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28200279/492336):

> As mentioned before, Android 5.0 has /system/bin/app_process as a symlink to /system/bin/app_process32. Since a symlink cannot be pulled with adb pull, the ndk-gdb script will not be able to work as-is.

I just logged into the android emulator VM and replaced the symlink with a copy of the file:

```
C:\Users\sasho>adb shell
root@generic_x86:/ # mount -o rw,remount /system
root@generic_x86:/ # cd /system/bin
root@generic_x86:/system/bin # rm app_process
root@generic_x86:/system/bin # cp app_process32 app_process
```

And it worked after that!